# How to debug for TLS/SSL connection

Tags: docker, ssl, tls1.2

Ar first I made three files with these.

```
$ openssl genrsa 2048 > server.key
$ openssl req -new -key server.key > server.csr
$ openssl x509 -days 3650 -req -signkey server.key < server.csr > server.crt
```

Then,I made registry container by docker-compose which including `server.key` `server.crt` and port `5000` is open.

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    container_name: registry
    image: registry:2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/data:/var/lib/registry
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/certs:/certs
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/server.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/server.key
```

then in the localhost I rename `server.crt` to `ca.crt` and put the key `/etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp\:5000/ca.crt`.

Then I try to curl but in vain.

```
$curl https://docker.mysite.jp:5000/v2/ --cacert /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp\:5000/ca.crt

/etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp\:5000/ca.crt 
curl: (60) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

OK I see there is something wrong with `tls/ssl`

However how can I debug where to start??

---

```
$curl https://docker.mysite.jp:5000/v2/ --cacert /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp\:5000/ca.crt -vvv
```

here is the log

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x7f89b4800000)
* Connected to docker.mysite.jp (135.132.179.73) port 5000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp:5000/ca.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=Some-State; O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
*  start date: Mar 24 16:55:37 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 29 16:55:37 2120 GMT
* SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I set the SQDN for crt file. then error message changed.

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x7fb4de806c00)
* Connected to docker.mysite.jp (135.132.179.73) port 5000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp:5000/ca.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

but ,Then I restart with `docker-compose down` & `docker-compose up`, it fixed!!!

Comment: *"curl: (60) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate"* - This describes a problem with the certificate but you don't provide enough details about the certificate - only the command lines you used to create but not the actual values you've entered at the various prompts. Specifically, what did you enter as common name when creating the CSR/certificate since this is the value it is complaining about. It should match the domain in the URL you use.

Comment: mmm I didnt; type anytinng when making `server.csr`.....

Comment: Thank you I put the FQDN in crt and message changes. `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`. it must be progress.

Comment: Thanks you help me. MY problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute curl with `-vvv` option to see all steps. Also, you can try

> tcpdump

and

> wireshark

to see every network action at including network level 4.